# Gorm "Insert Ignore"

Tags: database, go, insert, go-gorm

I am trying to implement "Insert Ignore" in GORM. I tried `Create()` but I couldn't find a way to add `Ignore`. I also tried [Clause in Gorm](http://v2.gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html#Clause-Options),

```
DB.Clauses(clause.Insert{Modifier: "IGNORE"}).Create(&user)`.
```

However, I got an error says `Clauses undefined (type *"github.com/jinzhu/gorm".DB has no field or method Clauses)`.

I also tried to use `DB.Raw()`, but I don't know how to change the table each time since I have so many tables in my database. For example

```
DB.Raw("INSERT IGNORE INTO A/B/C/.. ... ...")`.
```

I have a lot of tables that will go through this function, each time I might insert into a different table.

I am wondering if anybody has experience with `Insert Ignore` in GORM. Thanks!

Comment: @ttrasn for `GORM` SO tag is `go-gorm`,  please  try to update tag also when edit :)

Comment: @Rono yep, sure ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

I think you are using `gorm v1`. but the code you need is on `gorm v2`.

first, you must get `Gorm v2` and `MySQL dialector` by run this commands on your terminal.

```
go get -u gorm.io/gorm // get gorm v2
go get -u gorm.io/driver/mysql // get dialector of mysql from gorm
```

then you can use `Clauses` of gorm.

this code will be work for you.

```golang
import (
   "gorm.io/gorm"
   "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
)


func main(){
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(MYSQL_CONNECTION_STRING), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }else{
        db.Clauses(clause.Insert{Modifier: "IGNORE"}).Create(&user)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Do you know if there is a way to `insert ignore` in `gorm v1`?

Comment: @RP Your welcome, As you said, you can use `DB.Raw`

Answer (score 0):

For `Gorm v2` the answer is clear: [Clause in Gorm](https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html#Clause-Options).

For `Gorm v1`, you can find the solution in `Gorm v1`'s tests.
refer: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/create_test.go#L285

```
    if DB.Dialect().GetName() == "mysql" && DB.Set("gorm:insert_modifier", "IGNORE").Create(&user).Error != nil {
        t.Error("Should ignore duplicate user insert by insert modifier:IGNORE ")
    }
```

I met the issue several times as lots of our team still have lots of code using `Gorm v1`...